# Conflict between microtype and syntax packages

Tags: fonts, pdftex, microtype, debugging, grammar

While using the [syntax](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw) package together with microtype, I stumbled on a strange error:

> Missing font identifier.<to be read again>\chardef <TEST> ::= `
>
> Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\chardef <TEST> ::= `

With the following **minimal example**, I was able to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<TEST> ::= `test'
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

When I remove microtype, this works fine. By coincidence, I also found a **hack that seems to solve the problem** by adding a `\lit*{}` command before the grammar definition, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\lit*{}
\begin{grammar}
<TEST> ::= `test'
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to resolve this error cleanly? What is causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** This has been fixed in `microtype` v3.0.

---

That's a bug in `microtype`, triggered by some of the more adventurous code of `syntax`. The following should fix it:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
\def\MT@is@opt@char#1\iffontchar#2\char#3\else#4\fi\relax{%
  \MT@ifempty{#1}{%
    \iffontchar#2%
      \expandafter\chardef
        \csname\MT@encoding\MT@detokenize@c\@tempa\endcsname=#3\relax
    \fi
  }\relax
}
\makeatother
```